# Alternative for `word-break: break-word`

Tags: css, word-break

Is there an **alternative** for `word-break: break-word` that works in firefox ?

**In firefox[Version 57.0]**

[image]

**In Chrome[Version 62.0.3202.94]**

[image]

Is there a way or an alternative to use `break-word` attribute in firefox also.? [*if it works in older versions it would be much better.*]

**Sample Code**

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.text-right {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-right">Sample text </td>
    <td>Sample texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext 000000000000000000000000000000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try this : word-break: break-all;

Comment: @stalinrajindian I don't want to use `word-break: break-all;` it will break all the words without repecting their structure.

Answer (score 11):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I think I found the answer.

I've always used `word-break: break-word` because it's perfect in most cases, if there is enough space it wraps and keeps the words, and if there's not enough space it breaks the word. [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) say that `word-break: break-word` is deprecated but will probably still works, but the real reason I started looking at an alternative is that visual studio doesn't auto-complete `break-word` anymore :)

Solution ?

[MDN - overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

> overflow-wrap: anywhere;

Wraps the words to new line, and only breaks the word if it need to.

"The property was originally a nonstandard and unprefixed Microsoft extension called word-wrap, and was implemented by most browsers with the same name. It has since been renamed to overflow-wrap, with word-wrap being an alias."

So `overflow-wrap` should be used instead of `word-wrap`.

```js
var s = document.querySelector('div');

function a(){
  s.removeAttribute('class');
  s.classList.add('a');

}

function b(){
  s.removeAttribute('class');
  s.classList.add('b');

}
```

```css
#class{
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 120, 120);
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

btn{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.a{
  overflow-wrap: normal;
}

.b{
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

```html
<span>overflow-wrap:</span>
<btn onClick="a()">Normal</btn>
<btn onClick="b()">Anywhere</btn>

<div id='class'>
  We need a very long word like Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious 
</div>

<i>There's also overflow-wrap: break-word;</i>
```

Comment: This works fine everywhere but not on Safari in early 2021 https://caniuse.com/?search=overflow-wrap%3A%20anywhere%3B.

Is there any easy way to "polyfill" or patch Safari, but not Chrome, Firefox or Edge?

Answer (score 7):

The [valid values of `word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) are as follows:

```
/* Keyword values */
word-break: normal; 
word-break: break-all; 
word-break: keep-all;

/* Global values */
word-break: inherit;
word-break: initial;
word-break: unset;
```

> The `word-break` CSS property specifies whether or not the browser
>   should insert line breaks wherever the text would otherwise overflow
>   its content box.
>
> Chrome, Safari and other WebKit/Blink browsers also support the
>   unofficial `break-word` value which is treated like `word-wrap: break-word`.

So could you use `word-wrap: break-word` instead?

Comment: But `word-wrap: break-word` will only break the line if there are words if its a line without a word then it will overflow the div. But `word-break: break-word` in chrome it will break the line if its overflow the div and it will also respect the word also.[ am looking for a solution like this]

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Could you add a code snippet in your OP?

Comment: I have put a sample code for you guyz[it's a quick one], I hope you get the point.

Comment: I just found this on CodePen - any help?
https://codepen.io/katydecorah/pen/ywmBE

Comment: also this on GitHub which fixes a lot of issues: https://github.com/ftlabs/ftcolumnflow

Comment: and this 2014 blogpost: https://miketaylr.com/posts/2014/01/word-break-break-word.html

Comment: Thankyou for your references and you time you spend for that. But I am wondering if there any new post or hack regarding this issue. without the help of `script`. For your effort, I will give you +1, but am not looking for an answer like this sorry.

Comment: thanks for the upvote :) I think you will need to use some sort of polyfill script, I'm afraid. I found `overflow-wrap: break-word` but that didn't work in Firefox either :(

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1296042) on Bugzilla, word-break: break-word now works in Firefox as of version 67. It got implemented in [this changeset](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/c1075c1f1605).

break-word does come with this note in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break):

> This deprecated API should no longer be used, but will probably still
>   work.

Comment: It must have been updated. It seems to have been updated to just have a comment in the syntax indicating that break-word is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate words in your case you have two CSS properties: word-break and word-wrap:

- word-break: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp
- word-wrap: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: This I know bro. my question is there any solution for creating the `break-word` in firefox

Comment: @weBer the value break-word doesn't exist for the property word-break, so I think it's normal that firefox returns an error. What do you expect?

Comment: "Chrome, Safari and other WebKit/Blink browsers also support the unofficial `break-word` value which is treated like `word-wrap: break-word`." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: @mickaelw I was just asking if there is an alternative to the same behaviour.

Comment: @weBer I just read your comment on yvonne answer. Can you add a sample into your question?

Comment: @mickaelw I have put a sample code for you guyz[it's a quick one], I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility with legacy content, the word-break property also supports a deprecated break-word keyword. When specified, this has the same effect as word-break: normal and overflow-wrap: anywhere, regardless of the actual value of the overflow-wrap property. source [here](https://rocketvalidator.com/html-validation/css-the-value-break-word-is-deprecated)
It worked perfectly on my websites.